# Catching the OutOfMemoryError in Java

Tags: java, out-of-memory, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want to write a large file but I am getting `OutOfMemoryError` which is expected. I want return a message for `OutOfMemoryError`. I have used `try-catch` but it is not able to catch the error. Please suggest

Comment: I know this sounds unhelpful, but once your JVM is out of memory, it can't be relied on to do anything much.  Is there some way you can stop the OutOfMemoryError from happening at all?

Comment: Seconding what David said. You need to look into what's causing the `OutOfMemoryError` first, as it's (almost) always user error.

Comment: Can you provide a minimalist example that exhibits the behavior you're describing?

Comment: You can `catch` exceptions, not errors. Exception is a problem that (may be) recoverable. Error - a way bigger problem that you can't do anything about. In the case of OutOfMemory what are you going to do if you were allowed to catch it? You're still out of memory at that point. You can't free anything without using (even low amounts of) memory to do so.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your file and what is the size of you Xmx?

The best way to <s>handle</s> find the cause of OutOfMemoryError is by running you program with jvm parameter`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` . This will generate an heapdump in the form of .hprof file. You can then analyze this file with Java Memory Analyzer, to see where the memory leak is.

Comment: At this moment I don't need to handle the error. Now, For every task, a status gets updated (if parquet file has been written successfully). If there is any error while writing, I need to set the status as failed. But I am not able to catch that exception. Here is my code snippet:                                  dfTask.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(filePath);                  on failure I need to send a message

Comment: By handle I mean find the cause of what is causing the error.